# Will removing the on/off switch remove the electricty from the ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, fans

I  first turned off the breaker and disconnected my light and fan switch. Then I covered the switch wires separately.

Will this disconnect my fan from the live wires with the breaker turned back on? Will there still be electricity in the fan wires? My goal is to replace the ceiling fan with a new one with the power on.

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. Why, if you already have the ability to turn off the circuit breaker, would you try to change a fan with the breaker on?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate   I imagine that breaker controls other stuff that OP does not want off for long.  We all know how long a 5 minute job really takes.

Comment: A picture showing the wires and inside of the box will help.  A single cable to the box, probably not.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like you are asking the wrong question. Why do you think you *need* to work with the power on?

The answer is, unfortunately, "it depends." If the switch is connected via a switch loop, *no*, this will not remove power from the wires at the lamp fixture.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a safe way to work on wiring with the power on.   The problem is several wiring configurations are possible, and some of them have hot wires in places not controllable by the switch.

In fact, some wiring configurations mean that even turning the circuit's breaker off may not be enough.

Are you planning to reuse the old fan?  Rather than disconnect the old fan's wires at the wire nuts, how about simply cutting them off? Then, you can simply nut onto them, and won't have to open up any hot or neutral bundles.